# What is an easier combinatorics book than Miklos Bona's "A Walk through Combinatorics"?

Tags: combinatorics, book-recommendation

I'm going through Miklos Bona's "A Walk through Combinatorics" (for a second time) and am having a lot of trouble understanding it. I find that most of the problems are too difficult and that it gets very complex at times. Chapter 6, the chapter on cycles in combinatorics, was so complex that I had to skip it entirely. Even in other chapters, I am unable to do over 50% of the problems on my own. I am currently an independent learner. I have all of the background information necessary to study the book. It's just that the book is too difficult. Could anybody recommend me an easier book that would still cover a basic combinatorics course?

Comment: Well, I started Combinatorics with base in the book: Discrete Mathematics: Elementary and Beyond. The authors are L. Lovasz, J. Pelikan, K. Vesztergombi; Springer

Comment: Two obvious answers are van Lint & Wilson "A Course in Combinatorics" and Peter Cameron "Combinatorics", see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29137/good-combinatorics-textbooks-for-teaching-undergraduates). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171543/where-are-good-resources-to-study-combinatorics.

Comment: @Dietrich: Your first choice surprises me: I find the style of van Lint & Wilson much less accessible than Bóna’s.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree. I took a look at the book and found the mathematics to be much more complicated. I also want to focus on the enumerative side of combinatorics which the book seems to not have.

Comment: @sjgandhi2312: Have you looked at Bóna’s *Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics*? I’m not sure how much it differs from the other book in the parts that overlap.

Comment: While I enjoy Wilson (though not as much as Stanley), I agree with @BrianM.Scott that it is probably not what you are looking for. I enjoyed the much easier read [Brualdi](http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Combinatorics-Edition-Richard-Brualdi/dp/0136020402) as an undergrad (you can probably find it free online).

Comment: If you are looking for a good undergraduate-level book, consider http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Techniques-Combinatorics-KHEE-MENG-KOH/dp/9810211392 (Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics). It is strong in the areas of recurrence relations, generating functions (ordinary and exponential), and principle of inclusion-exclusion, and has many interesting competition type problems. The table of contents can be found at: http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789814355162_fmatter

Comment: `I am unable to do over 50% of the problems on my own.` I guess this is completely fine. Bona has many hard exercises, If you are able to work out near 50% of exercises then I would say you can do the book by putting in just a little more effort. Bona is a classic!